# New-PowerBIReport command returns 400 BadRequest with specific pbix file in PowerShell, but manual upload of same file works in PowerBI app

Tags: powershell, powerbi

I am encountering an issue while using the `New-PowerBIReport` command in PowerShell. The command I am using is:

`New-PowerBIReport -Path 'C:\Example file.pbix' -WorkspaceId 'xxxxxxx-8xxx-4xxx-axxx-1xxxxxxxxx'`

The issue is that this command throws a 400 BadRequest error for a specific pbix file, but when I manually upload the same pbix file to the same workspace on the Power BI app, it works without any issues [[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlEeR.png)]. *Note I cannot share the file itself.

##### 400 Error

```
[ERROR] New-PowerBIReport : Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'
[ERROR] At D:\GitHub\Project\test.ps1:11 char:1
[ERROR] + New-PowerBIReport -Path 'C:\Example file.pbix' -Wo ...
[ERROR] + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ERROR]     + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (Microsoft.Power...ewPowerBIReport:N 
[ERROR]    ewPowerBIReport) [New-PowerBIReport], HttpOperationException
[ERROR]     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRe 
[ERROR]    quest',Microsoft.PowerBI.Commands.Reports.NewPowerBIReport
[ERROR]
```

I have already verified that the workspace ID is correct, and I have the necessary access permissions to perform the command.

I have also tried using different pbix files and different workspaces, but the problem exists only for this particular pbix file; any other pbix file successfully uploads via the ccommand.

I appreciate any suggestions or help regarding why this might be happening. Thank you.

Comment: The file may be in a different group.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/sharepoint-scenario-embed-report#step-3-grant-access-to-the-report